# Excel - add all X in column and then multiply

Tags: excel

I am looking for a code to write for excel.  My objective: to count all the "X" in a column and multiply by $25.

Example:  If you did a task, put an "X" in cell B3 and if you did it again, put an "X" in B4; and so fourth on down the column.  I would like another cell to add up all the "X" in the column and multiply by $25.  So if 4 cells in column B had an "X", then this certain cell would equal $100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use countif for the count then multiply it by $25.00

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,"X")*25
```

Comment: With this spreadsheet I am making, I am going for a "clean" look, where if the cell equals zero then I would like for the cell to be empty.  When I use this formula, the cell has $0.00 all the time. I have tried different methods to show empty but am unable to get it to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"X")=0,"",COUNTIF(B:B,"X")*25)`

Comment: Thanks much!!  I'll give it a shot!